# Jquery return value of delayed function doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I  have two functions in jquery. I call the first function and inside it, with a delay of 2 seconds, I call the second function.

I want to get the returned value of second function, but it doesn't work.

If I replace return with `console.log(param2)` it works fine.

```
function func2(param2) {
    return param2;
};


function func1(param1) {
    param1++;
    window.setTimeout(func2,2000,param1);
}
func1(1);
```

Comment: Returned values from functions that are called as timer event handlers (and, in general, any sort of event handler) are generally just ignored. There's no mechanism for directly doing what you're asking, but you can have "func2" invoke a callback (another function).

Comment: What you want to do with return value? we could suggest some alternate solution for that

Comment: these 2 function are just an example. this scripts are injected from an webbrowser from vb.net. and i use return value to make other calculations on vb. i already have a solution n vb. i invoke this scripts separately and get corrensponding returns and manipulate in vb. but i wanted to do it 1 one invoke - @ParagBhayani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update #1:**

there's a better way of doing it with Javascript Promise (an easy async callback method)

```
function func2(param2, resolve, reject){
  resolve(param2);  
}

function func1(param1) {
   param1++;
   var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     window.setTimeout(func2,2000,param1,resolve,reject);
   });
   return promise;
}

func1(1).then(function(func2_value) {
  alert(func2_value); 
});
```

**Update #2: (Solution)**

After your comment about what you are trying to do, here is my solution to your problem. I've tested this and its working. Hope this will address your problem.

Use MessageEvent to trigger C# function when you finish doing your processing on func2(). Refer to my below example,

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(@"C:\Naren\Setups\Gecko\xulrunner");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Add a event listener to get a call back from javascript function -> func2()
        geckoWebBrowser1.AddMessageEventListener("Func2Result", ((string s) => this.ProcessFunc2Result(s)));

        // Load a sample HTML content to the browser
        geckoWebBrowser1.LoadHtml(@"
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>                 
                    <meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=UTF-8"">
                    <script type=""text/javascript"">
                        function func2(param2){
                            var result = 'Result from Func2 -->'+param2;
                            var e = new MessageEvent('Func2Result',{'view':window,'bubbles':false,'cancelable':false,'data':result});
                            document.dispatchEvent(e);
                        }
                        function func1(param1){
                            param1++;
                            window.setTimeout(func2,2000,param1);
                        }
                    </script>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <H1><center>Jquery return value of delayed function doesn't work</center></H1>
                    <p><center>Solution is to add a MessageEvent to javascript and trigger C# function on func2 result</center></p>
                    <p><center>This page has a javascript function that can fire a C# function</center></p>
                </body>
            </html>
        ");


    }

    // Function receives Func2 result
    private void ProcessFunc2Result(string result)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(result);
    }

    // Button click event triggered from a button on your form
    // Trigger javascript function func1()
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:func1(1)");
    }
}
```

[image: Result screenshot of the above example code]

This way, you trigger func1() by calling

```
geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:func1(1)");
```

and func1() triggers func2() using setTimeout after 2 seconds,

```
window.setTimeout(func2,2000,param1);
```

and func2() triggers c# function with result using MessageEvent

```
var result = 'Result from Func2 -->'+param2;
var e = new MessageEvent('Func2Result'{
      'view':window,'bubbles':false,'cancelable':false,'data':result
});
document.dispatchEvent(e);
```

Note the EventListener which maps the javascript event message "Func2Result" with C# function ProcessFunc2Result()

```
geckoWebBrowser1.AddMessageEventListener("Func2Result", ((string s) => this.ProcessFunc2Result(s)));
```

I have used GeckoFx version 31.0.0.1 and Xulrunner version 31.0

I did this in C#, there is not much difference to do the same in VB .NET.

Comment: i am trying to accomplish this.
i have a winform which uses geckofx web browser.
it navigates to my webpage. invoke my funct1 which reades an element on the page. funct1 returns its Id. i grab this id from the page and i make browser to navigate to it. it waits 5 seconds to load and than invoke funct2 with parameter i got from funct1 it reads this new elemenet and return to winform. i have to do 2 invokes from vb. i wanted to accomplish from 1 invoke. this is the whole idea.

i home i am clear @Naren

Comment: @user1361208: Assuming 5 secs for navigation load time will not be reliable right? why can't you use geckoWebBrowser1_Navigated() event to do anything after navigation?

Comment: i have already solved in vb. by calling each function separately. but since i have to merge the 2 results from each function,i thought it was possible to accomplish with jquery. but i cannot read a variable(in this case func2_value from vb). Your solution with promises is a good one but again i cannot read the value from vb. As i stated before with alert and console.log it gives me the value but with return no.

Comment: @user1361208: Updated the answer with a solution to your question. Pls check and confirm.

Comment: @user1361208: Great. Please mark this as solution if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

> i want to get the returned value of second function.

You can only get the return value of a function that **you** are calling. But you are *not* calling `func2`. The browser does at some point in the future. There is no way for you to get the return value, unless `setTimeout` provides a way. But it doesn't.

You could change your code as shown below:

```
function func1(param1) {
    param1++;
    window.setTimeout(function(param1) {
        var result = func2(param1);
        console.log(result);
    }, 2000,param1);
}
```

Now you *are* calling `func2` and you can do something with the return value. However, you won't be able to get the return value inside `func1`, because, again, `func1` does not (directly) call `func2`.

Comment: Someone's making sense in the answers. +1

Comment: Re downvotes: What is wrong with my answer? If you let me know, I might be able to correct it.

Comment: in my example if i replace reurtn statement with console.log it works ok. while with your sample it gives undefined @FelixKling

Comment: @user1361208: I just forgot to pass the argument along (which isn't really relevant to the issue at hand).